# Which systems define EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK as different values?

Tags: unix, posix, errno

Just curious.  Which systems providing both EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK `#define` them as different values?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There were some... http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Error-Codes.html

> Portability Note: In many older Unix systems, this condition was indicated by EWOULDBLOCK, which was a distinct error code different from EAGAIN. To make your program portable, you should check for both codes and treat them the same.

http://lists.parisc-linux.org/hypermail/parisc-linux/9895.html

> On some SysV systems EAGAIN != EWOULDBLOCK. I think we inherited the 
>   errno definitions from HPUX...

Older AIX is such system too: http://programming.itags.org/unix-linux-programming/81597/

> HP-UX (and older versions of AIX)

For AIX I found the list of codes: http://homepage3.nifty.com/owl_h0h0/unix/job/UNIX/tutorial/error.html

> 11     EAGAIN;
>   54     EWOULDBLOCK

OS/390 too: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/zvbaIz8u6TzsQHHjfzOi

> OS/390 and other platforms where EWOULDBLOCK != EAGAIN

There is fuller table: http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html

```
        SUSv3   AIX 4.3,5.1 HP-UX 11.22 Solaris 9,10    Linux 2.4.28,2.6.9  IRIX 6.5[4] OSF1    FreeBSD 5.2.1   OSX 10.3.8  MSVC6
EAGAIN  1   0   Resource unavailable, try again [3] 11  Resource temporarily unavailable    11  No more processes   11  Resource temporarily unavailable    11  Try again   11  Resource temporarily unavailable    11  ditto   35  Resource temporarily unavailable    35  Resource temporarily unavailable    11  Resource temporarily unavailable

EWOULDBLOCK 0.9 0   Operation would block [3]   54  Operation would block [2]   246 Operation would block   11      11  Operation would block   11  Resource temporarily unavailable    35  Operation would block   35  Operation would block   35  Operation would block
```

So, AIX 4.3,5.1; HP-UX 11.22 and OSF1 uses different codes for EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: Looks like the most recent of the EAGAIN != EWOULDBLOCK OS releases is about 2002.  Thanks.

Comment: Some code should work on older releases too. I know some current users of OS/2 (not ecomstation, but the original Os/2, last version released at 2001). E.g. arp portable library; firefox 3.5 was ported to OS/2 too,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a couple of systems.

In GNU C library they always have the same value.

Comment: linux/parisc, some HP-UX, some other old unices.. that's what google shows, I don't know more. Just use both, if they are the same the compiler will happily optimize it.