# How to exit a blocking recv() in Windows?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winapi, winsock

I have a thread that contains a blocking `recv()` call, something like this:

```
{   
    while(1)
    {
        recv(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }       
}
```

Now what I want to do is to signal the `recv()` function from another thread to make it exit its blocking state. I have read the following answer from another question that talks about how to do this in Unix ([How to let a thread which blocks on recv() exit gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267146/how-to-let-a-thread-which-blocks-on-recv-exit-gracefully)):

> Either:
>
> 1. Set a read timeout, with `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVTIMEO`, and whenever it triggers check a state variable to see if you've told
>      yourself to stop reading.
> 2. If you want to stop reading the socket forever, shut it down for input with `shutdown(sd, SHUT_RD)`. This will cause `recv()` to return
>      zero from now on.
> 3. Set the socket into non-blocking mode and use `select()` with a timeout to tell you when to read, adopting the same strategy with a
>      state variable as at (1) above. However non-blocking mode introduces
>      considerable complications into the send operation, so you should
>      prefer (1) or (2) above.
>
> Your pseudo-code lacks EOS- and error-checking. I hope it doesn't
>   really look like that.

I am not interested in the first and third solutions because the CPU will probably get exhausted, and based on my testing, the second solution is not supported in Windows (am I right?). So is there another solution to exit a blocking `recv()`?

Comment: Option #3 is the one that's used most of the time, and is the most portable one. I have no idea what those mysterious "considerable complications" are. It's fairly cut, and dry.

Comment: You don't need to set the socket to non-blocking mode when using `select`. Just use `select` with a short timeout (say 200msec). When `select` returns, check the state variable to see if you're supposed to stop. Only call `recv` if the socket has data.

Comment: It is quite nonsense to use a blocking function if you don't want it to block ...

Comment: @Olaf I do want it to block, I just want to also be able to make it exit its blocking state so that I can terminate the thread when closing my application.

Comment: @Trevor: So you apparently don't want it to block! Or did you see some magical "unblock" call in the library? There is a reason these libraries provide the fundamental functionality only. That's why they are called "low-level" libraries. You still don't explain what the actual problem is with `select` etc. (on Linux you can use `poll`/`epoll`, but Windows is - as always not that modern.

Comment: If you don't care about portability very much, you can use `WSARecv` in overlapped mode. After the call, you can use `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for the either completion event, or for a special event that you use to inform the thread that you don't wish to wait any longer.

Comment: @MartinDrab: And that is a POSIX function?

Comment: @Olaf But if I used a non-blocking socket, then I would keep looping to see if `recv()` has any data, and even if I used `select()`, I also must use a timeout and keep looping. Also, is there a rule that says that a blocking function can never be allowed to exit its blocking state from another thread?

Comment: Yes, when you use `select`, you must use a timeout and keep looping, but it uses 0% of the CPU (as long as you use a reasonable value for the timeout). Just try it.

Comment: @user3386109 Great to know, thanks :)

Comment: @Olaf No, it is not. You did not say you want a POSIX-compatible solution (which would be one with the `select` call).

Comment: @MartinDrab: I'm not the asker, but " the second solution is not supported in Windows" made me think OP wants a portable solution. Maybe I'm wrong, though

Comment: @Trevor: Carefull with assumptions. Profile your code **iff** you experience actual problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *blocking* `recv()` exits only if:

1. data is read.
2. The read times out (SO_RCVTIMEO).
3. The connection is closed.

If none of those options are viable for you, you will have to simply not call `recv()` in blocking mode until you know there is something waiting to be read, as reported by `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect()`, or `WSAEventSelect()`.

Otherwise, re-write your socket logic to either:

1. use the socket in non-blocking mode.
2. use `WSARecv()` or `RIOReceive/Ex()` with Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port. An I/O operation can be canceled with `CancelIo/Ex()`.

Comment: Wouldn't CancelSynchronousIo() work?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I do not know. I have not tried it, and it is not documented whether it works with socket APIs.