# Non-blocking I/O issue

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, unix, io

I don't have much experience with asynchronous I/O on sockets. Recently I had to implement a TCP client that would connect to a server in a seperate thread and wait for input data and that in a non-blocking manner so that the thread could be terminated immediately by simply setting some flag varaible from the control thread. My solution was setting socket non-blocking and implementing a loop that called recv over and over again if errno was E_WOULDBLOCK and exited loop when flag variable *run* wasn't set anymore. It was like that:

```
while(run) {
   if( -1 == recv(...))
   {
       if(errno == E_WOULDBLOCK)
            continue; 
       else
            break; 
   }
   else
   {
       process_data(...); 
   }
}
```

The question is: how good is this solution in terms of CPU usage? Will using select/poll/epoll be more effective?

And another one question: is there any way to make blocked *select*, *read* or *connnect* call return immediately from other thread?

Comment: What is the language (C, C++)!?

Comment: It shall better be: `if ((errno == E_WOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))`

Comment: @alk, [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7003234/132382), yes.

Comment: Beware, that on Linux, [recv may block after select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351994/will-read-ever-block-after-select), therefore use both non-blocking IO and select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: how good is this solution in terms of CPU usage? Will
>   using select/poll/epoll be more effective?

It is **terribly** inefficient. It is probably the worst way you handle multiple connections. 
Consider that each `recv` is a system call: it requires a context switch. A context switch is not expensive, but computing a context switch in a high frequency loop will likely full the CPU usage.
Also, if you were to sleep between a call and another, to "soften the loop", you would end up paying a delay between data receive and processing; the more connections you have, the higher it'll be felt.

`select` basically tells the kernel: "I want these sets of fds to be monitored by you and also be signaled as soon as something happens.". Your process will enter a waiting state and become ready when an event is delivered. Meanwhile, the CPU may serve other processes.

You may use a blocking multiplexer and handle each work in a separate thread (maybe from a thread pool), which is very efficient. But it depends on what you're doing.

> And another one question: is there any way to make blocked select, read or connnect call return immediately from other thread?

Well, yes. But is something you want to have? As @alk said, you can send them a signal. In addition, for `recv` and `connect`, you might want to use `select`/`poll` or any other multiplexer with timeout properties; it might be harder to program, though.

Answer (score 2):

> how good is this solution in terms of CPU usage?

Busy waiting is very inefficient.

> Will using `select`/`poll`/`epoll` be more effective?

Yes.

> is there any way to make blocked `select`, `read` or `connnect` return immediately

Yes, send the blocked thread a signal. The function in question will return `-1` and `errno` shall be set to `EINTR`. When setting up the signal handler take care of how [`SA_RESTART`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) is handled by your compiler's implementation.

Comment: Using a signal to wake up another thread may be unsafe if you don't know the state that the other thread is in.  If the other thread happens to /not/ be blocked on the `select`, the signal may break whatever is actually happening.

Comment: On might very well setup the signal handler before entering the section expected to block and disable the handler on leaving the this section. @user3553031

Answer (score 0):

The code that you give uses a tight poll loop (ie, it doesn't block until input is received or even wait between polls).  Since the CPU is constantly checking for input, it is likely to be very inefficient.  Generally, polling like that is only appropriate if the maximum time until input is available is tightly bounded; in the vast majority of cases, you should block using something like `select` or `epoll`.

If you have one thread that's blocked on a `select` (or similar), one easy way to force it to resume from a different thread is to create a pipe, add the read end of the pipe to the select, and write to the pipe from another thread whenever you want to unblock the select thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are programming in C and have a decent kernel version, [`pselect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect) is the way to go.

Waiting for input and signals simultaneously is a well-known problem and there are many good discussions about the problems and solutions associated with it.  You might find [this discussion](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-12.html) a good start.